# Active Admin in rails - csv limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was downloading a csv of a model using active admin 0.3.4 that had around 12,000 records. But the csv was limited to only 10,000 rows of data. Is there a way to not limit the number of rows in the csv download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a function called max_csv_records in lib/active_admin/resource_controller/collection.rb
of the github source code..
Change the default constant to how much ever you need

Comment: This has changed in more recent versions of ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

It's [hardcoded](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L276)

I put this in my config/intializers/active_admin.rb

```
# Monkey patch to increase the number of records
# exported in csv download -default is 10k
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module DataAccess
      # in active admin 0.6
      def max_csv_records
        30_000
      end
      # needed for current active admin master
      def max_per_page
        30_000
      end
    end
  end
end
```