# ActiveAdmin CSV export timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin

I'm trying to export csv **ActiveAdmin v0.6**

It is working in my local and staging, but giving **timeout error in production**.

I even downloaded my  production database to test in local, csv file is generated and exported,

but it took almost 5 minutes to complete request and **export 3K user records**.

I tried monkey patching max_csv_records and max_per_page like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355126/active-admin-in-rails-csv-limit). But my limit has not exceeded and it did not work.

Please help me to fix timeout error and export csv file using ActiveAdmin.

Comment: If you can, switch to ActiveAdmin 1.0.0

Comment: It is built at least 2 yrs ago, with lots of features. I'm afraid that code could break. Doesn't it?

Comment: There are some changes between the versions, that brakes thing, most of them can be fixed with some find and replace. To say more, I need to take a look on your ActiveAdmin resource files. You are on the latest 0.6.6 version? Some other way is, you can compare the old CSV export and the new one and you maybe can backport that code.

Comment: @ashwinkumar, looks like there is sort of n+1 query problem while exporting, check your logs to ensure it isn't.

Comment: Same code and database from production is working fine in development, but I could not make it work in production. I fixed with alternate solution with custom code using action_item and collection_action features.

Comment: @ashwinkumar, pls show your resource code